# How can I use bluetooth bluez in python 3 <?

Tags: python, bluetooth

Using a raspberry pi 3 running Raspbian-jessie.

I have been trying to install python bluez library to use with python 3.
Trying the:
apt-get install bluez pybluez bluetooth

Installs on python 2.

I've downloaded bluez from https://github.com/karulis/pybluez
using: 
python setup.py install 
Installs on python 2

I tried: 
python3 setup.py install

ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

Am Stumped, can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2):

try to install:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pybluez
```